# why can the kernel be not finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am very new to modules and couldn't understand this:

Suppose $\phi:R^n\rightarrow M$ is an $R$-linear map. I thought $\ker(\phi)$ is finitely generated since $R^n$ is generated by the canonical basis $\{e_i\}$. But this seems to be wrong as one of the problems sets that as an extra condition.

I really appreciate it if anyone can correct my understanding and hopefully give a basic counterexample.

Comment: But $\ker(\phi)$ need not contain elements of the canonical basis, so even though the canonical basis is finite and generates $R^n$, that alone doesn't tell you much of anything about $\ker(\phi)$.

Comment: You are asking if a submodule of a finitely generated  module is also finitely generated. That is not in general true. That will depend of the ring $R$, for instance a PID.

Comment: You are stumbling onto the whole concept of Noetherian rings and modules. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_module It is indeed very suprising at first to realize that this is a special property and cannot be just assumed without condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not restrictive to assume that $\phi$ is surjective, in particular that $M$ is finitely generated. The condition that $\ker\phi$ is finitely generated is known to be “$M$ is finitely presented” and, in general, a finitely generated module need not be also finitely presented.

It's not so difficult to prove that if $M$ is finitely presented, that is, there exist $n$ and an $R$-linear map $\phi\colon R^n\to M$ such that $\phi$ is surjective and $\ker\phi$ is finitely generated, then *for every* surjective $R$-linear map $f\colon L\to M$, if $L$ is finitely generated then $\ker f$ is finitely generated.

On the other hand, a commutative ring $R$ can have nonfinitely generated ideals; if $I$ is such an ideal, then the canonical projection $\pi\colon R\to R/I$ provides an example of a finitely generated module, namely $R/I$, which is not finitely presented. And the classical example is the ring $R=k[x_1,x_2,\dotsc]$ of polynomials in infinitely many variables, with $I$ the ideal generated by the monomials.

In view of the theorem above, for *no* surjective linear map $\phi\colon R^n\to R/I$, you can have that $\ker\phi$ is finitely generated.

A (commutative) ring $R$ is *Noetherian* if each of its ideals is finitely generated. This is equivalent to saying that every finitely generated $R$-module is finitely presented.